# Comparing keys and values std::maps

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have two maps. I need to compare both keys and values.

```
map<char,int> mymap;
mymap.insert(pair<char,int>('a', 1));
mymap.insert(pair<char,int>('c', 2));

map<char,int> mymap1;
mymap1.insert(pair<char,int>('b', 1));
mymap1.insert(pair<char,int>('d', 2));
```

Example key `a` from `mymap` is compared with `b` and `d` in `mymap1`.

If same key found in other `mymap1` I need to compare the values.

So I need to compare keys and values. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: Shouldn't be hard. Can you please show us what you have tried so far and where are you struck ?

Comment: `mymap == mymap1;`

Comment: @nwp I think OP is not looking for if both the maps are equal.

Comment: What should the ultimate outcome of this process be? What result do you expect to obtain in the end?

Comment: Are `mymap` and `mymap1` in your example supposed to compare equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to find out if both maps are equal just use `mymap1 == mymap2` - it is already implemented in `std::map`. If you need someting more complex use something like this:

```
auto it1 = mymap1.begin();
auto it2 = mymap2.begin();
while( true ) {
   bool end1 = it1 == map1.end();
   bool end2 = it2 == map2.end();
   if( end1 and end2 ) break;
   if( !end1 and ( end2 or it1->first < it2->first ) ) {
       std::cout << "key:" << it1->first << " not found in map2" << std::endl;
       ++it1;
       continue;
   } 
   if( end1 or it2->first < it1->first ) {
       std::cout << "key:" << it2->first << " not found in map1" << std::endl;
       ++it2;
       continue;
   } 
   if( it1->second != it2->second ) {
       std::cout << "values for key:" << it1->first << " are different" << std::endl;
   }
   ++it1;
   ++it2;
}
```

just replace `std::cout` output with your logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
for (auto iter = mymap.begin(); iter != mymap.end(); iter++) {
    auto iter1 = mymap1.find(iter->first);
    if (iter1 != mymap1.end()) {
        // compare iter->second with iter1->second
    }
}
```

Comment: That's way too ineffective, 2 iterators could be used in one loop without `find()`. Or even `map1 == map2` if OP needs to find out if maps are equal.

Comment: I was aiming for simplicity, seeing as how OP is new to std::maps.

Comment: @Slava: how would you implement this using 1 loop and 2 iterators without `find()`?

Comment: SImplicity should not invalidate validity, how OP suppose to check that a key from `mymap1` is missing in `mymap`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau already provided that in my answer

Comment: @Slava OP has stated "If same key found in other `mymap1` I need to compare the values." - they haven't said anything about checking if a key in `mymap1` is missing from `mymap`.

Comment: @frslm OP also says "So I need to compare keys and values." And you should remember that you provide answer not only for OP but for other readers.

Comment: @Slava Pedantically, this solution complexity is `O(N * log2(M))`, whereas yours is `O(N + M)`. This solution is faster when `N < M` and `log2(M) < M/N`, for example, `N=8` and `M=256`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin add another scan of keys from mymap1 in mymap to compare apples to apples